# How do I connect PC to router (ethernet for internet) and PC to laptop (WiFi for file sharing (LAN))?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lan, file-sharing

I'm looking to configure my network as follows:

1. PC to router via ethernet for Internet

Why: high speed/stable/reliable connection between router and PC; segregation from WiFi because I intend on using WiFi for wireless VR & (see below laptop use-case)

2. PC to laptop via WiFi

Why: see below laptop use-case

Laptop use-case:

1. Data backup (file sharing required)
2. Web server (to host my web app - I want the ability to access it in a browser on my PC)
3. 2a. I'd like to remotely access my laptop from my PC using
   TeamViewer to develop/perform maintenance on my web app.

The laptop will be in another room in my house which is why I want a wireless connection between the PC and laptop.

Given my PC has ethernet and Wifi (6), I've assumed that I can use both of them simultaneously to achieve the above.

Problem:

When ethernet cable is connected between router and PC, I am unable to use my PC's WiFi to achieve "2. PC to laptop via WiFi". Thus, I cannot achieve the laptop use-case.

The PC and laptop are on Windows 10.

My research has had me add fMinimizeConnections = 0 to the registry and change my ethernet adapter to Priority & VLAN Disabled.

These 'fixes' appeared to promise a solution to my problem, but instead enabled me to connect to my router via ethernet and WiFi, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is what I'm trying to do, possible? If so, how?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can connect the laptop and PC together using the router. Connect the laptop to the router by WiFi, and the PC to the router by Ethernet. Now the laptop and PC are on the same LAN. Inside that LAN, with many routers, the IPv4 address of each will be 192.168.1.*n*, where *n* might be *1* for one device, *2* for the next device, etc. If one device is a web server, the other can access it at its IP address. One can also use [Windows Virtual Desktop](https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/) to directly access the other device, or [use file sharing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-10-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf) for backup or to access data on another device. *Caveat*: Generally, throughput is slower from PC<-->router<-->PC than straight through from one device to the internet.
2. You can also use a [Windows device as a mobile hotspot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-your-windows-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot-c89b0fad-72d5-41e8-f7ea-406ad9036b85).
   [image: Windows Mobile WiFi Hotspot]

Comment: Thank you! Is it impossible to have both ethernet and WiFi adapters active serving the different purposes I was looking for?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- when used as a hotspot, both adapters **are** active.